# E: unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu word by word and

> sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full

has failed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the error message in the subject of my query above.
Anyone know what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317253/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-desktop-full-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/) by [SANDY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21545/sandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SANDY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21545/sandy/) on 2019-03-02**:
the keyserver succeeded and yes, I can ping sites on web so connected, and non of -desktop or -ros-base succeeded either, giving the same "not found" message

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-02**:
What is the output of:

- `uname -a`
- `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`
- `lsb_release -a`
- `sudo apt update`
- `apt-cache search ros-kinetic-ros-base`

Please *edit* your original question to append this information.

**Comment by [SANDY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21545/sandy/) on 2019-03-02**:
problem solved

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-02**:
Please do not delete questions that have been resolved/have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanks, sorted now my ros-latest.list.d reference was faulty, it all works now, thanks

---

Originally posted by [SANDY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21545/sandy/) with karma: 16 on 2019-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0